# Delete picture in .docx file

Tags: java, xwpf

Do anyone have any idea to delete pictures in .docx file? I'm using XWPFDocument and had tried like this. Please help.

```
List<XWPFPictureData> piclist = document.getAllPictures();              
for (int i = 0; i < piclist.size(); i++)     
{
    for (XWPFParagraph p : document.getParagraphs())         
    {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null)
        {
            runs.remove(piclist);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
ERROR [main] (DocxUtil.java:303) - 
Exception Caught: null java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.remove(Collections.java:1078) at 
com.test.util.DocxUtil.processImage(DocxUtil.java:296) at 
com.test.util.DocxUtil.main(DocxUtil.java:37)
```

Comment: You tell us what you've tried, but not what happens: Do some pictures remain? Do *any* pictures get deleted? Does it hang?

Comment: It threw out error

ERROR [main] (DocxUtil.java:303) - Exception Caught: null
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.remove(Collections.java:1078)
 at com.test.util.DocxUtil.processImage(DocxUtil.java:296)
 at com.test.util.DocxUtil.main(DocxUtil.java:37)

And also I'm not sure whether my approach is correct or not. Please advice me how to proceed further.

Comment: I have tried this code and I am getting an `UnsupportedOperationException` exception

Comment: I'm not sure whether my approach is correct or not. I tried like this. But didnt work. Thrown error. Please help me to take out this activity.

Comment: Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: I doubt this operation is supported in POI. I am still looking. Check if docx4j supports removing images.

Comment: ok..will check with docx4j

Comment: No one has any idea regarding this? Please help me to provide some suggestions at least

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove images in .docx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839147/remove-images-in-docx-file)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
runs.remove(piclist);
```

1. `remove()` is not supported on result of `List<XWPFRun> getRuns()`. Apache POI code doesn't support it. That's why you get UnsupportedOperationException. It is the expected behavior.
2. You try to remove one `List<XWPFPictureData>` from a List of XWPFRun. It cannot work.

Here is code working well:

```
for (XWPFParagraph par : document.getParagraphs()) {
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < par.getRuns().size()) {
        XWPFRun run = par.getRuns().get(pos);
        if (run.getEmbeddedPictures().size() > 0) {
            par.removeRun(pos);
        } else {
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

On more point: your code uses Apache POI. You should tag this question with "apache-poi".